# Fastest way to remove duplicates from UNION ALL (without using UNION) on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table with hundreds of millions of rows, where I want to get a single list of the unique values from 2 **indexed** columns **from the same table** *(with no unique row ID)*.

To illustrate this, let's say we have a table with a `fruits` column and a `veggies` column, and I want to build a `healthy_foods` list with the  unique values in both columns.

I have tried the following queries:

**with UNION**

```sql
WITH cte as (
    SELECT fruit, veggie
    FROM recipes
)
SELECT fruit as healthy_food
         FROM cte
         UNION --  <--- 
         SELECT veggie as healthy_food
         FROM cte;
```

**with UNION ALL then DISTINCT ON**

```sql
WITH cte as (...)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (healthy_food) healthy_food FROM  --  <--- 
(SELECT fruit as healthy_food
     FROM cte
     UNION ALL --  <--- 
     SELECT veggie as healthy_food
     FROM cte) tb;
```

**with UNION ALL then GROUP BY**

```sql
WITH cte as (...)
SELECT fruit as healthy_food
         FROM cte
         UNION ALL --  <--- 
         SELECT veggie as healthy_food
         FROM cte
GROUP BY healthy_food; --  <---
```

(and adding `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` and `GROUP BY` on each SELECT from the UNION)

The UNION ALL gets executed super fast, but all the duplicate-removing combinations I've tried take +15mins.

How could I optimize this query, taking into account that the 2 fields/columns come from the same table and are indexed?

*(or alternatively, what would be the least expensive way to keep track of all unique values? maybe a trigger inserting on a UNIQUE table, or a view?)*

Comment: What's wrong with `select fruit from recipes union select veggies from recipes`? If both columns are indexed separately, the engine should scan the indexes without hitting the heap even once.

Comment: If you are showing a list of hundreds of millions of rows to the user, that's bound to take some time. But... does it make sense in the first place?

Comment: @TheImpaler just `UNION` takes 15 minutes, while the ones with `GROUP BY` clauses take <6min. Maybe I should change the index type? It's a text field.

(Not showing the entire list anywhere, I just want to do some processing on each unique value - only once)

Comment: Roughly how many duplicates among fruits, among veggies, and *between* fruits and veggies? Actual (relevant parts of) table definition, and always your version of Postgres would be instrumental, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are many duplicates among fruits and / or veggies, but not so many *between* fruits and veggies (like the names in your example suggest), and since you have an **index** for both of them, emulating an index skip scan (a.k.a. loose index scan) will work wonders:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE fruit AS (
   (
   SELECT fruit
   FROM   recipes
   ORDER  BY 1
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT fruit
           FROM   recipes
           WHERE  fruit > t.fruit
           ORDER  BY 1
           LIMIT  1)
   FROM   fruit t
   WHERE  t.fruit IS NOT NULL
   )
 , veggie AS (
   (
   SELECT veggie
   FROM   recipes
   ORDER  BY 1
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT veggie
           FROM   recipes
           WHERE  veggie > t.veggie
           ORDER  BY 1
           LIMIT  1)
   FROM   veggie t
   WHERE  t.veggie IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT DISTINCT healthy_food
FROM  (
   SELECT fruit AS healthy_food FROM fruit
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT veggie AS healthy_food FROM veggie
   ) sub
WHERE  healthy_food IS NOT NULL;
```

Just `DISTINCT` instead of `DISTINCT ON` (like you tried) in the outer `SELECT`, since we are dealing with a single column.

See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893968/select-distinct-is-slower-than-expected-on-my-table-in-postgresql/66894500#66894500)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

You might as well use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` + `DISTINCT` in the outer `SELECT`. Only avoided that because you explicitly asked for it. But I don't see the point.

Comment: This one has blown my mind! `UNION` by itself takes 16 minutes, the `GROUP BY` variants take <6mins, but this one did it in... **33 SECONDS!**
Hats off to you (and I will further investigate this topic, as your reply has incited great curiosity in me)

Comment: If there number of distinct values is [very] small compared to the total number of rows, this strategy will indeed be blazing fast. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
select distinct r.fruit
from recipe r
union all
select distinct r.veggie
from recipe r
where not exists (select 1 from recipe r2 where r2.fruit = r.veggie);
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on:

- `recipe(fruit)`
- `recipe(veggie)`

If your statistics are up-to-date and you are using a recent version of Postgres, then the `select distinct` should use the index.  And then the `not exists` should use it as well.  The query should not have any additional duplicate elimination.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate indexes on `fruit` and `veggie` this query should be reasonably quick

```sql
SELECT fruit AS healthy FROM recipes
 UNION 
SELECT veggie AS healthy FROM recipes;
```

But you'll need separate indexes on those two columns so each side of the UNION can have a useful index.

You could use a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rules-materializedviews.html) for this application.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW healthy_food AS 
SELECT fruit AS healthy FROM recipes
 UNION 
SELECT veggie AS healthy FROM recipes;
CREATE INDEX healthy ON healthy_food (healthy);
...

SELECT healthy FROM healthy_food ORDER BY healthy;
```

Selecting from the view will be fast. But you'll have to routinely update the view like this. The refresh operation will incur the cost of the base query.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW healthy_food;
```

If your application can tolerate it being out of date between refreshes, this is a good way to proceed.  If the base query is still too expensive you can do the refresh once a day at zero-dark-thirty.

Comment: Still, there's no filtering predicate. The OP wants the whole table, twice. Not going to be fast.

Comment: @O.Jones: There is no *loose index scan* in Postgres, yet. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks. @ErwinBrandstetter