# Subquery with GROUP BY and MAX won't use index

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

I have this table in PostgreSQL 15.3 (corresponding to a Django model):

```
                                             Table "public.myapp1_task"
         Column          |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                     Default
-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------
 id                      | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('myapp1_task_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at              | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at              | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 kind                    | character varying(12)    |           | not null |
 status                  | character varying(12)    |           | not null |
 environment             | character varying(7)     |           | not null |
 data                    | jsonb                    |           | not null |
 result                  | jsonb                    |           | not null |
 sent_at                 | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 response_at             | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 priority                | smallint                 |           | not null |
 sequence                | integer                  |           |          |
 result_attachment       | character varying(100)   |           | not null |
 taxes                   | jsonb                    |           | not null |
 myapp2_item_id          | bigint                   |           |          |
 source                  | character varying(8)     |           | not null |
 user_id                 | bigint                   |           |          |
 custom_actions          | jsonb                    |           | not null |
 
Indexes:
    "myapp1_task_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "myapp1_task_user_id_76a104e9" btree (user_id)
    "myapp1_task_myapp2_item_idd_441d91cb" btree (myapp2_item_id)
    "sequence_idx" btree (sequence DESC NULLS LAST)
    "sequence_mc_idx" btree (sequence, myapp2_item_id DESC NULLS LAST)
```

**Goals**: for each `myapp2_item_id`, find the row with the highest sequence.

I added the last two indexes related to the `sequence` column.

Using Django ORM, I'm trying to filter a queryset, here's the code:

```
queryset = Task.objects.all()
sequences = queryset.filter(item=OuterRef("item")).exclude(sequence__isnull=True).order_by("-sequence").distinct().values("sequence")
max_sequences = sequences.annotate(max_seq=Max("sequence")).values("max_seq")[:1]
filtered_queryset = queryset.filter(sequence=Subquery(max_sequences))
print(filtered_queryset.query)
```

which translates that into this SQL statement. Note the subquery with `group by` and `max` aggregates:

```
SELECT "myapp1_task"."id"
FROM "myapp1_task"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp2_item"
                         ON ("myapp1_task"."myapp2_item_id" = "myapp2_item"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp2_user" ON ("myapp2_item"."user_id" = "myapp2_user"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp2_category"
                         ON ("myapp2_item"."myapp2_category_id" = "myapp2_category"."id")
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp2_user" T5 ON ("myapp1_task"."user_id" = T5."id")
WHERE "myapp1_task"."sequence" = (SELECT "subquery"."max_seq"
                                          FROM (
                                          SELECT MAX(U0."sequence") AS "max_seq", U0."sequence"
                                                FROM "myapp1_task" U0
                                                WHERE (U0."myapp2_item_id" =
                                                       ("myapp1_task"."myapp2_item_id"))
                                                GROUP BY U0."sequence"
                                                ORDER BY U0."sequence" DESC
                                                LIMIT 1) subquery)
```

Sadly, it's very slow on a fairly large table (>1M rows). Inspecting the `explain` result, I got this `-> seq scan` on the subquery, so none of the new indexes are used:

```
Seq Scan on myapp1_task  (cost=0.00..5525.25 rows=3 width=8)
  Filter: (sequence = (SubPlan 1))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Subquery Scan on subquery  (cost=8.30..8.33 rows=1 width=4)
          ->  Limit  (cost=8.30..8.32 rows=1 width=8)
                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=8.30..8.32 rows=1 width=8)
                      Group Key: u0.sequence
                      ->  Sort  (cost=8.30..8.31 rows=1 width=4)
                            Sort Key: u0.sequence DESC
                            ->  Index Scan using myapp1_task_myapp2_item_idd_441d91cb on myapp1_task u0  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=4)
                                  Index Cond: (myapp2_item_id = myapp1_task.myapp2_item_id)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. How can this be improved?

Comment: 1) I haven't broken down the entire query but this `...FROM "myapp1_task" U0 WHERE (U0."myapp2_item_id" = ("myapp1_task"."myapp2_item_id")` to me indicates the sub-query is going to run over all the rows, hence the Seq Scan. 2) You should include the Django code that generated this query as update to your question.

Comment: It’s an empty table, no point in doing an index scan. That would be slower. If the table does have data, you might want to run analyze to update the statistics. And check auto analyze

Comment: Consider instructions for Postgres performance questions: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 2):

Either you or your ORM (or both) have twisted and obfuscated the SQL statement to a degree that any RDBMS would have a hard time to distill an efficient query plan from it. After removing a lot of cruft, the (equivalent) statement reads:

```sql
SELECT t.id
FROM   myapp1_task t
LEFT   JOIN myapp2_item i     ON t.myapp2_item_id = i.id
LEFT   JOIN myapp2_user iu    ON i.user_id = iu.id
LEFT   JOIN myapp2_category c ON i.myapp2_category_id = c.id
LEFT   JOIN myapp2_user tu    ON t.user_id = tu.id
WHERE  t.sequence = (
   SELECT t1.sequence
   FROM   myapp1_task t1
   WHERE  t1.myapp2_item_id = t.myapp2_item_id
   ORDER  BY t1.sequence DESC
   LIMIT  1
   );
```

(`GROUP BY` and `MAX` were useless noise in the original.)

The correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause filters rows from `myapp1_task` where `sequence` sorts first in descending sort order among rows with the same `myapp2_item_id` - in a very expensive way. Due to your peculiar query and table definition, any rows are eliminated where `myapp2_item_id` or `sequence` is `null`, or any other row with the same `myapp2_item_id` and `sequence IS NULL` exists.

All `LEFT JOIN` rows are just noise since the `SELECT` list only returns `myapp1_task.id` anyway. The only possible effect of those joins would be to multiply rows if the left side has duplicates, which seems an unlikely endeavor.

#### Solution

You later added:

> **Goals:** for each `myapp2_item_id`, find the row with the highest sequence.

Still does not clarify how to deal with `null` values. Nor how to deal with duplicates. Nor what to return exactly. All of which matters.

**Assuming:**

- The combination `(myapp2_item_id, sequence)` is actually `UNIQUE`.
- You want the highest not-null sequence.
- You want to return whole rows (`SELECT *`) - which is often wasteful nonsense.

Then the query boils down to just (!):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (myapp2_item_id) *
FROM   myapp1_task
ORDER  BY myapp2_item_id, sequence DESC NULLS LAST;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

About `DESC NULLS LAST`:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

#### Index

The best index for this query is a multicolumn index with matching sort order **leading** `myapp2_item_id`: `(myapp2_item_id, sequence DESC NULLS LAST)`.

For only few rows per value in `myapp2_item_id`, the index will not help (much) - especially for `SELECT *`. A sequential scan can be as fast or faster. The index becomes more useful with a growing number of rows per group. For large numbers, special query techniques are superior. See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893968/select-distinct-is-slower-than-expected-on-my-table-in-postgresql/66894500#66894500)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/34715134#34715134)

Postgres 16 will ship with a number of performance optimizations in this area, due late 2023.

Comment: many thanks for youyr reply, I added the goals in the original question.