# PostgreSQL fast query to get most recent rows

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a PostgreSQL table with a bunch of events, each containing a timestamp, id, and action. I expect a few million events per day, and expect the table to grow to several billion rows eventually.

I want to query the most recent events for each item (a few hundred thousand distinct ids) before a given date, but currently the query is extremely slow, taking 1-2 hours minimum (the table currently has around 100 million rows). Is there a way to speed up this query?

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    with events as (
        SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) AS rn,
          *
        FROM event_updates
        WHERE time_stamp < '2023-05-01'
    )
    SELECT * FROM events WHERE rn=1 ORDER BY item
) a;
```

DDL for table

```
CREATE TABLE "event_updates" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval("event_updates"::regclass),
  "time_stamp" timestamptz(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  "item" varchar(32) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" NOT NULL,
  "event_type" int2,
)
PARTITION BY ();
ALTER TABLE "event_updates" OWNER TO "owners";
```

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for the table and indexes involved? (in plain text) Your current query most likely doesn't take the most recent data, just data older than May 2023. And it takes all data older than May 2023 and that could be years of data. Depending on when you started collecting data.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql?tab=Votes

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've just added in the DDL for the table. I think the query does get the most recent data older than May 2023. I'm selecting all rows older than May 2023, and then taking the first row of that partitioned by the item when sorted by the timestamp.

Comment: What's `PARTITION BY ()`? And are there no indices on this table? Not even a `UNIQUE` constraint? Then of course it's slow.

Comment: No indexes? That makes it slow by design.

Comment: Please provide your *actual*, working table definition (incl. all constraints), all indexes and other information as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info Is there an additional table with unique IDs? (important!)

Comment: I assume *"most recent events for each id"* is supposed to mean *"most recent events for each `item`"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need an index on item and the timestamp. Second, you select the max(timestamp) for each item and then select the record you need:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_event_updates_item_time_stamp
    ON event_updates(item, time_stamp);

SELECT *
FROM event_updates
    JOIN (SELECT item
               , MAX(time_stamp) time_stamp
          FROM event_updates
          GROUP BY item
          ) sub USING (item, time_stamp);
```

You might want to create the index per partition, concurrently, to avoid locking issues. It takes longer however.

Comment: `I want to query the most recent events for each **id**`. why `item`?

Comment: @Kosh Because of the original query, this part: `PARTITION BY item ORDER BY time_stamp DESC`

Answer (score 2):

Emulate an index skip scan for best performance. Should be the fastest way:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   event_updates
   ORDER  BY item, time_stamp DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT e.*
      FROM   event_updates e
      WHERE  e.item > c.item
      ORDER  BY item, time_stamp DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) e
   )
TABLE  cte;
```

In combination with a **matching index** (essential):

```
CREATE INDEX event_updates_item_time_stamp_idx ON event_updates(item, time_stamp DESC);
```

See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893968/select-distinct-is-slower-than-expected-on-my-table-in-postgresql/66894500#66894500)

More optimization may be possible.
I'll explain some more after you have disclosed requested information.

Comment: `I want to query the most recent events for each **id**`. why `item`?

Comment: @Kosh: My educated guess: that's a typo by the OP, `id` is just the surrogate PK of the table, and the OP really meant *"for each item"*.

Comment: `item` is varchar(32) and my guess was it's a kind of a name behind the `id` added for human-readability; on the other hand, `id` is int(4) which makes `a few hundred thousand distinct ids` look doubtable to me.

Comment: @Kosh: `id` is a serial column drawing from a sequence. Wouldn't make sense.

Comment: sure, thanks! I missed that.