# Compound index with date function doesn't allow index-only scans?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to use a compound (multicolumn) index on a table to assist in creating daily report counts. I am using Postgres 13, and my table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE inquiries (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    identity_id bigint NOT NULL,
    received_at timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    purpose_id bigint NOT NULL,
    location_id bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX "inquiries_DATE_index" ON inquiries USING btree
   (date(received_at), location_id, purpose_id, identity_id);
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DATE(received_at), location_id, purpose_id, COUNT(DISTINCT identity_id)
FROM inquiries
WHERE (DATE(received_at) >= $1)
  AND (DATE(received_at) <= $2)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Explain output looks like this:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=43703.28..45785.49 rows=10950 width=19)
  Group Key: (date(received_at)), location_id, purpose_id
  ->  Sort  (cost=43703.28..44092.34 rows=155627 width=16)
        Sort Key: (date(received_at)), location_id, purpose_id
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on inquiries  (cost=5243.60..27622.21 rows=155627 width=16)
              Recheck Cond: ((date(received_at) >= '2023-11-01'::date) AND (date(received_at) <= '2023-11-30'::date))
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "inquiries_DATE_index"  (cost=0.00..5204.70 rows=155627 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((date(received_at) >= '2023-11-01'::date) AND (date(received_at) <= '2023-11-30'::date))
```

The index doesn't seem to help, the query takes a long time to execute. If I add a date column to the table and use that instead of `date(received_at)` then the query works better and the query plan changes to:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..85199.58 rows=10980 width=19)
  Group Key: pacific_date, location_id, purpose_id
  ->  Index Only Scan using inquiries_pacific_date_index on inquiries  (cost=0.43..77813.12 rows=727666 width=16)
        Index Cond: ((pacific_date >= '2023-11-01'::date) AND (pacific_date <= '2023-11-30'::date))
```

I guess I can do this if I can't find a better way but it seems kind of redundant. Is there a way I can write my original query so it makes better use of the index?

Comment: Your "slow" query is showing a lower cost (45785) than your "fast" query (85199). Either `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` will show the costs are wrong or your balance of costs for e.g. cpu vs disk os wrong for your machine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have run the explain with similar row counts.  The first explain was done with less rows than the second.  The first query takes 20 seconds with 10M rows while the 2nd one takes 3 seconds.  The production table contains about 9B rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Drop-in fix

Like Laurenz explained, index-only scans currently (pg 16) suffer from a corner-case limitation in Postgres. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)

> However, PostgreSQL's planner is currently not very smart about such
> cases. It considers a query to be potentially executable by index-only
> scan only when all *columns* needed by the query are available from
> the index.

The manual has more details. One workaround is to "include" the *column* itself in the index (replacing the old one):

```
CREATE INDEX inquiries_date_plus_idx ON inquiries
   (date(received_at), location_id, purpose_id, identity_id) INCLUDE (received_at);
```

Allows index-only scans for your original query. But it also increases the size of the index - by 8 bytes per row in your case.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6EMcIJOp)

#### Better

Create an index on bare columns, without expressions:

```
CREATE INDEX inquiries_received_at_plus_idx ON inquiries
   (received_at, location_id, purpose_id, identity_id);
```

(A plain index also often has additional utility for other purposes.)
And adjust your query slightly, to be **exactly equivalent**:

```sql
SELECT received_at::date, location_id, purpose_id, COUNT(DISTINCT identity_id)
FROM   inquiries
WHERE  received_at >= $1
AND    received_at <  $2 + 1  -- !
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Input `$1` and `$2` must be type `date`, and `received_at timestamp`, as indicated in the question.

`count(DISTINCT col)` is typically slow in my experience. This may be faster, yet:

```sql
SELECT received_at::date, location_id, purpose_id, count(*) AS dist_identities
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1,2,3,4)
          received_at::date, location_id, purpose_id, identity_id
   FROM   inquiries
   WHERE  received_at >= $1
   AND    received_at <  $2 + 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6EMcIJOp)

And if there are many duplicates per `(received_at::date, location_id, purpose_id, identity_id)`, an emulated index-skip scan may be much faster, yet. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893968/select-distinct-is-slower-than-expected-on-my-table-in-postgresql/66894500#66894500)

##### Upgrade

Postgres has improved performance for big data with every major version over the past years. Consider upgrading to the [latest version Postgres 16](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) (at the time of writing). Should give you an immediate, additional boost.

Comment: Thanks to you and Laurenz for your invaluable help.  I went with just including the received_at column in the index per your fiddle ( CREATE INDEX inquiries_date_plus_idx ON inquiries (date(received_at), location_id, purpose_id, identity_id) INCLUDE (received_at) ).  I think I tried all the variations that you suggested.  The subquery with DISTINCT ON was slightly slower.  Creating an index on the bare column didn't seem to help.  I think this first column in the index needs to be non-varying (date) vs varying (timestamp)?  Pardon my use of terminology, I only know enough sql to be dangerous.

Comment: There is one attack angle with substantial potential: if there are many duplicates on `(date(received_at), location_id, purpose_id, identity_id)` (like I mentioned in my answer) - so that `COUNT(identity_id)` >> `COUNT(DISTINCT identity_id)` on avg. in your query. Then more optimization will pay.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that due to a limitation in PostgreSQL, it won't use an index-only scan with your index, because the index contains an expression. You'd have to add `received_at` to the index (in addition to `date(received_at)`) to make it work.

Comment: Or you can turn the problem around and query for a timestamp `>= '2023-11-01 00:00:00'`