# select distinct values and exclude rows by condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

There is a table with columns `category not null`, `sub_category default null`.

- `category` is always set
- `sub_category` is optional

I need to select `distinct category,sub_category`  from table and

- exclude records where sub_category is not null and null
- keep record if there is only one combination of `category` + `<null>`

```
category    sub_category  
girl_toys        fluffy
girl_toys        dolls
drawing          <null> -- keep it since only one null sub_category
paining          red_color
paining          <null> -- exclude since there is non null sub_category
```

expected result:

```
category    sub_category  
girl_toys        fluffy
girl_toys        dolls
drawing          <null> -- keep is since drawing has only one null
paining          red_color -- <null> record excluded since there is non null sub_category exists
```

Comment: Add another non-null painting to the sample data, and adjust the expected result if needed.

Comment: I believe you could just use min/max aggregate formulas, both of which would pick the min (or max) non-null value over null, and only return null if that was the only option. `SELECT category, MAX(sub_category) FROM yourtable GROUP BY category;`.

Comment: @JNevill, that would only work if there's only one non-null sub_category  per category. (Indeed as in the sample data, but I assume there can be blue, green and yellow paintings too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of many:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT category, sub_category 
FROM   tbl t1
WHERE  sub_category IS NOT NULL
   OR  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM tbl t2
         WHERE  t2.category = t1.category
         AND    t2.sub_category IS NOT NULL
         );
```

I assume you also want to keep one copy if there are multiple instances of the same `category` + `null`. You really only want to exclude `category` + `null` if there is another row for the same `category` with a not-null `sub_category`. At least that's what your "expected result" suggests.

If the table is big and there are many duplicates per `(category, sub_category)`, performance can be optimized with an emulated index-skip scan. See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893968/select-distinct-is-slower-than-expected-on-my-table-in-postgresql/66894500#66894500)

Comment: Thank you, I had monstrous group by, count query before. My table is just 1K row, so perf is not an issue. Redability was main criteria. Your solution is much better.