# Count distinct values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Google Sheets has a function `COUNTUNIQUE` where you can get the number of distinct values. What is the simplest way to simulate this in SQL? Is the following the simplest approach?

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT 1 a UNION ALL
    SELECT 2   UNION ALL
    SELECT 1  
) SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM tbl
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't get simpler than:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT a) ...
```

An index on `(a)` cannot help (much).

For a big table with low cardinality in `a` (many duplicates), an emulated index skip scan performs (much) better. Like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (   -- parentheses required
   SELECT a
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY 1
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT l.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT a
      FROM   tbl t
      WHERE  t.a > c.a
      ORDER  BY 1
      LIMIT  1
      ) l
   )
SELECT count(*) FROM cte;
```

Certainly not "simpler", though. And requires index support.
See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893968/select-distinct-is-slower-than-expected-on-my-table-in-postgresql/66894500#66894500)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)