# Fill a column with repeated thresholds

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Assume I have two tables `a` and `b`, each containing a series of dates:

Table `a`:

| day_date |
| --- |
| 2020-1-1 |
| 2020-1-2 |
| 2020-1-3 |
| 2020-1-4 |
| 2020-1-5 |
| 2020-1-6 |
| 2020-1-7 |
| 2020-1-8 |
| 2020-1-9 |
| 2020-1-10 |

and table `b`:

| id | some_date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-1-3 |
| 0 | 2020-1-6 |
| 0 | 2020-1-8 |
| 1 | 2020-1-2 |
| 1 | 2020-1-5 |

I want to create a new table `c` which contains both `day_date`, `id` and `some_date`, but now `some_date` contains only values such that the minimum value above some given threshold is used, i.e.:

| day_date | id | next_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-1-1 | 0 | 2020-1-3 |
| 2020-1-2 | 0 | 2020-1-3 |
| 2020-1-3 | 0 | 2020-1-6 |
| 2020-1-4 | 0 | 2020-1-6 |
| 2020-1-5 | 0 | 2020-1-6 |
| 2020-1-6 | 0 | 2020-1-8 |
| 2020-1-7 | 0 | 2020-1-8 |
| 2020-1-8 | 0 | null |
| 2020-1-9 | 0 | null |
| 2020-1-10 | 0 | null |
| 2020-1-1 | 1 | 2020-1-2 |
| 2020-1-2 | 1 | 2020-1-5 |
| 2020-1-3 | 1 | 2020-1-5 |
| 2020-1-4 | 1 | 2020-1-5 |
| 2020-1-5 | 1 | null |
| 2020-1-6 | 1 | null |
| 2020-1-7 | 1 | null |
| 2020-1-8 | 1 | null |
| 2020-1-9 | 1 | null |
| 2020-1-10 | 1 | null |

My idea was to filter a cross join of the two, e.g.:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE some_next AS (
  SELECT
    day_date,
    id,
    CASE WHEN some_date > day_date THEN some_date ELSE NULL END AS next_churn_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY day_date, id ORDER BY some_date ASC) AS rn_next
  FROM a CROSS JOIN b
  WHERE some_date > day_date OR day_date >= (SELECT MAX(some_date) FROM b bb WHERE bb.id = b.id
);

CREATE TABLE c AS (
  SELECT * FROM some_next WHERE rn_next = 1 ORDER BY id, day_date
);
```

I was looking for a simpler solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Are `day_date` and `some_date` both of `date` type?

Comment: @Schwern yes, they are both of type `date`

Comment: If performance matters, tell us your version of Postgres, and basic cardinalities: how many rows per table? How many distinct `id` values? And exact table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) showing data types and constraints are always instrumental. Also, do you run the query for the whole table(s) or a small selection?

Comment: @norok2 Why do you do it in two steps? If you merge your two queries, `WHERE rn_next = 1` gets taken into account when the window function runs as `Run Condition: (row_number() OVER (?) <= 1)` which speeds things up. [Here's a demo of the three solutions here, starting with yours, after merging.](https://dbfiddle.uk/J-rbCa4K)

Answer (score 1):

A **simpler** solution - tested on Postgres, not Redshift (which is not Postgres at all):

```sql
SELECT a.day_date, b1.id
    , (SELECT b.some_date
       FROM   b
       WHERE  b.id = b1.id
       AND    b.some_date > a.day_date
       ORDER  BY b.some_date
       LIMIT  1) AS next_date
FROM   a
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM b) b1
ORDER  BY 2, 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LsrTU-WI)

With an index on `b(id, some_date)` it can perform decently, as the **correlated subquery** results in one very fast index-only scan for each result row.
There are (much) faster ways to get distinct `b.id` for only few distinct values in a big table. See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893968/select-distinct-is-slower-than-expected-on-my-table-in-postgresql/66894500#66894500)

Comment: Redshift is based on Postgres 8, but that was over 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

We can start with a cross join to get all combinations of IDs and days.

```
select
  day,
  id
from days
cross join ( select distinct id from some_days )
order by id, day;
```

Then use that to rank the some_days proximity to the days (dropping the order by, it's unnecessary).

```
with days_ids as (
  select
    day,
    id
  from days
  cross join ( select distinct id from some_days )
)
select
  di.day as day,
  di.id,
  sd.day as some_day,
  row_number() over (
    partition by di.day, di.id
    order by sd.day asc
  ) as row_num
from days_ids di
left join some_days sd on di.day < sd.day and di.id = sd.id
order by di.id, di.day, row_num
```

And select only those rows with a row_number of 1.

```
with days_ids as (
  select
    day,
    id
  from days
  cross join ( select distinct id from some_days )
), 
matched_days as (
  select
    di.day as day,
    di.id,
    sd.day as some_day,
    row_number() over (
      partition by di.day, di.id
      order by sd.day asc
    ) as row_num
  from days_ids di
  left join some_days sd on di.day < sd.day and di.id = sd.id
)
select day, id, some_day
from matched_days
where row_num = 1
order by id, day
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/NFz_bmd5).

Comment: I am not much convinced this is any simpler than what I proposed

Comment: @norok2 That's for you to decide. It might perform better, your `select max` subquery might get expensive. Right now I can only replicate your solution. If you really want simpler, describe the problem you're solving; what will you use table C for? How will you keep it up to date? That will give folks more latitude. For example, you might be able to eliminate table A and use `generate_series` instead, but we need to know more about what the days in table A represent.